# How to create SnowSQL query programmatically

Tags: dynamic-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I am new to SnowFlake and exploring new things every day. I am stuck with the below scenario.

```
    SELECT 
   '{COL}' AS field_name,
    a.{COL}AS old_value,
    b.{COL}AS new_value FROM A JOIN B ON(...)
    WHERE a.{COL} != b.{COL}
```

I want to parameterize COL. And it may have multiple values like *COL=col1,col2,col3*. And then I want 3 queries separated by *UNION* as shown below.

```
    SELECT 
   'col1' AS field_name,
    a.col1 AS old_value,
    b.col1 AS new_value FROM A JOIN B ON(...)
    WHERE a.col1  != b.col1 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
   'col2' AS field_name,
    a.col2 AS old_value,
    b.col2 AS new_value FROM A JOIN B ON(...)
    WHERE a.col2  != b.col2 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
   'col3' AS field_name,
    a.col3 AS old_value,
    b.col3 AS new_value FROM A JOIN B ON(...)
    WHERE a.col3  != b.col3
```

Is there any way to achieve this in SnowSQL ( SnowFlake )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible to create dynamic SQL in SnowFlake. The most common way is to use Stored Procedures and/or UDFs using javascript to generate the SQL and execute it.

In the javascript you can use string replacement, loops, etc to create lists of parameters, join conditions etc.

[Here's the general documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-overview.html)

and here's a couple useful javascript snippits

```
//Set Up a multi-column Join Condition based on the columns in ColumnList
//Example output: "a.column1 = b.column1 AND a.column2 = b.column2"
ConditionArray = [];
ColumnList.forEach(function(column){
  conditionArray.push("a." + column+ " = " + "b." + column);
});
joinCondition = conditionArray.join(" AND ");


//Executing a script, and returning the output from a resultSet
//You can chain these calls for cleaner/shorter code
SQLQuery = "SELECT 1;"
SQLStatement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: SQLQuery });
SQLResultSet = SQL_Statement.execute();
SQLResultSet.next();
SQLResultSet.getColumnValue(1)
```

You can then create loops to execute multiple similar queries, or combine them together with UNIONs and then execute that.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-overview.html

Comment: Thanks David Garrison. This helped me to achieve the dynamic behavior.